# Get Instagram media with a specific tag in specific time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am in a situation where I need to get all the photos posted to instagram with a particular tag in a specific time period. Basically, I want to show all the images those were posted in between certain time period (Probably dates). But as of now I can't see any option that is being provided in the [instagram tags api](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent).

I have tried using the same api to get the photos and loop through it with a condition to check the `created_time`. But I found that the response is not ordered by created_time. Is there any way I can achieve the same, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option to do this. Other APIs have `max_timestamp` and `min_timestamp` options, but tag media endpoint does not have this option.